# How do you distinguish filenames when reading/writing unicode filenames?

Tags: macos, file, go, unicode, filesystems

I am writing `go` code but I don't believe its unique to go so lets generalize it. Imagine a user via go code creates three files with three distinct unicode names. Notice the last letters of the filename are different.

- `καθέδρα.txt`
- `καθέδρᾳ.txt`
- `καθέδραι.txt`

In `go`, these three strings are three different unique strings. It appears, that if you try to create three files with these three names, you end up with two files saved to disk. The second and third filenames appear to be treated as identical files. So when the script writes three user created files, one goes "missing".

If you write `καθέδρᾳ.txt` then `καθέδραι.txt` you end up with only the first filename.

If you write `καθέδραι.txt` then `καθέδρᾳ.txt` you end up with only the first filename.

How do you guard in golang against strange OS/X filename behavior in unicode? It appears to think two different strings are one filename.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the internals of the filesystem used. No general answer is possible.

Comment: @Volker I understand where you are coming from, you could blame it all on OS/X and wash your hands of it. But that doesn't help anyone. Should, for example, golang scripts do some kind of system call to detect operating system and file system type before saving, and detect possible strings before saving in some cases, and if so, what is the best way to do that detection.

Comment: This is all opinion based and cannot be answered in general. The general solution is: Don't use this type of filenames. If the user insists on using this type of filenames than any problems are the users fault, this has nothing to do with code. Note that the name of the language is Go, Go is compiled and thus not really a scripting language.

Comment: Impossible as the 2nd string is 7 characters `\u03ba\u03b1\u03b8\u03ad\u03b4\u03c1\u1fb3` while the 3rd one is 8 characters `\u03ba\u03b1\u03b8\u03ad\u03b4\u03c1\u03b1\u03b9`. In UTF-8: 15 bytes `\xce\xba\xce\xb1\xce\xb8\xce\xad\xce\xb4\xcf\x81\xe1\xbe\xb3` vs. 16 bytes `\xce\xba\xce\xb1\xce\xb8\xce\xad\xce\xb4\xcf\x81\xce\xb1\xce\xb9`. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: This seems relevant: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties

Comment: @JosefZ I respect that you don't believe that OS/X treats the second and third filename as the same, you are welcome to believe that if you wish. I have no interest in debating reality. My question here is, given that OS/X presents these two filenames as the same to `go`, how do we handle that.  The disk format matters here, the default disk format will treat them the same.

Comment: Reality? Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] instead of a vague description…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you choose a case insensitive file system on OS/X, the case insensitivity process is more complex than our intuition would expect. Depending on the language, the rules are different.

- Uppercase a is A (in English).
- Uppercase of I is İ some languages.
- Apparently ᾳ equates to αι.

There is no real way to guard against this except to detect the file system type.

The cross platform way to prevent the problem would be to have your software write a file and read it back using a different "case" to detect if the problem exists.